# Are Windows Memory Mapped File contents always zeroed by default?

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, memory-mapped-files

I've determined empirically that, on my system, a memory mapped file created to be a certain size is always completely zeroed by default. For example, using the call

```
HANDLE hMM = 
    CreateFileMapping (h,
                        NULL,
                        PAGE_READWRITE,
                        0,
                        0x01400000,//20MB
                        NULL);
```

.. and writing into a mapped view of that file always results in a 20MB file that is completely zeroed, except where I have written non-zero data.

I'm wondering if uninitialized parts of the file can be assumed to be zeros. Is this behavior guaranteed on Windows in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [CreateFileMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation (*Remarks* section) explicitly states that

> If the file is extended, the contents of the file between the old end of the file and the new end of the file are not guaranteed to be zero; the behavior is defined by the file system.

so, if your file on disk starts empty, it's *not* guaranteed to be zeroed (since you are expanding it); I don't think that file system drivers would take the risk of leaking potentially sensitive information that way, but who knows, maybe some file system driver recycles pages already used for your process (and this shouldn't be a security risk).

On the other hand, I don't know if filesystems that do not offer security at all (e.g. FAT) would be so concerned to give you the content of the clusters that they happened to allocate for the new part of the file.

If, instead, you are creating a memory section not backed by a file on disk but by the paging file it's guaranteed that the memory you get is all zeroed:

> The initial contents of the pages in a file mapping object backed by the operating system paging file are 0 (zero).

This is guaranteed probably because when creating a memory-only paging file the memory manager has the complete control on what's going on, and it takes the pages from the blanked pages pool.

Answer (score 6):

All newly allocated pages are zeroed before they are made accessible to user-mode, because otherwise sensitive information could be leaked from kernel-mode or other processes. This applies to things like `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`/`VirtualAlloc` and `NtCreateSection`/`CreateFileMapping`.

I imagine the same concept extends to files, because any decent file system wouldn't want to leak information in this way.

EDIT: However, take that last paragraph with a grain of salt - both the documentation for CreateFileMapping and [SetEndOfFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365531.aspx) claim that the extended portion of the file is not defined. I'll do some more investigation.

EDIT 2: OK, the Win32 MSDN documentation **is definitely wrong**. The documentation for [ZwSetInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567096.aspx) states:

> If you set FileInformationClass to
>   FileEndOfFileInformation, and the
>   EndOfFile member of
>   FILE_END_OF_FILE_INFORMATION specifies
>   an offset beyond the current
>   end-of-file mark, ZwSetInformationFile
>   extends the file and pads the
>   extension with zeros.

So there you go. The extended portion *is* guaranteed to be zero.

Comment: Still, you should stick to the contract of the interface you're using, not to the implementation details; if the `CreateFileMapping` documentation says (*explicitly*!) that it's not guaranteed, then *it's not guaranteed*. The `ZwSetInformationFile` *is* an implementation detail, on Windows 9x `ZwSetInformationFile` wasn't there, and maybe on Windows 12 it won't even exist anymore.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Lies. Win32 is full of lies, and ever since I switched to using the Native API I have never trusted any Win32 documentation on MSDN. As a Windows Internals Expert I'm here to tell the truth about what really happens, not what Win32 claims is the truth. :D

Comment: @wj32: actually Win32 was designed "full with lies" to make applications work seamlessly on NT, 9x, (partially) on Win32s and on whichever kernel Microsoft will think for the future, without having them rely on platform-specific implementation details. Any well-behaved Win32 application should just rely on the Win32 contract to be sure to continue to work in future versions of Windows. Haven't you ever read Raymond Chen's blog? `:)`

Comment: @wj32: again, they are not lies, it's an encapsulation-like thing: you're targeting Win32? Then you rely on the Win32 guarantees. You're targeting native APIs? Then you can rely on the NT guarantees. The drivers are a completely different issue, it's implicit that they need to be changed (and sometimes rewrote completely) on kernel architecture changes; they have as a target an API which is known to be much more unstable than Win32 (I'm not saying that NT APIs are *that* instable, I'm saying that Win32 is *really* stable).

Comment: @Matteo Italia: You're completely correct. I'm trying to justify my answer - I'm providing the "internals" angle on what goes on, that's all.

Comment: @wj32: and in that I'm completely with you (actually you got my +1), it's really interesting to know how stuff works internally. My remark was just a "don't rely on it, or be ready to change your code, since in future such behavior may change" for the OP, not a critic to you. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for both the answers and the discussion. I found them both enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as pointed out by wj32. This is related to c2 requirements which NT has met since its birth. However depending on what you are trying to do, you should probably look into sparse files.